# API working on postman but refused connection in Flutter

Tags: php, laravel, flutter

```
postRequest() async {
    Map\<String, dynamic\> map = {
        'email': 'annafarah.9@gmail.com',
        'password': '1234',
    };

    try {
        var url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login');
        var response = await http.post(url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: jsonEncode(map)
        );

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
            print(responseBody);
            return responseBody;
        } else {
            print("try error ${response.statusCode}");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        print("Error catch ${e}");
    }
}
```

Error:

> I/flutter (25242): Error catch Connection refused

Comment: `127.0.0.1` = localhost. So you're trying to connect to an API on the same phone? You probably meant the IP address of your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try hosting your application on to the local IP and connect your phone with the same wifi or network. Such as:

**If you using Windows then:**

**For Wi-Fi connection**

1. Select Start > Settings > Network & internet > Wi-Fi and then select
   the Wi-Fi network you're connected to.
2. Under Properties, look for your IP address listed next to IPv4
   address.

**For Ethernet connection**

1. Select Start > Settings > Network & internet > Ethernet.
2. Under Properties, look for your IP address listed next to IPv4
   address.

**If you using Ubuntu then:**

> ifconfig -a

Which looks something like 192.168.x.x ex:- 192.168.0.100, 192.168.1.20..etc

open the terminal for that root folder which you want to host. Then run this command

> php -S 192.168.0.100:8000 -t public

you need to change this IP with your IP 192.168.x.x and port for you will host I prefer 8000 and use that IP address with port in your Flutter app.